# What is the denotation of the word 'population'?

Tags: meaning, connotation, language-change

I've seen the word **population** most commonly used in the context of the magnitude of a community or group e.g. "*The population of the United States is 320 million*". I have also seen it used to simply refer to the collective e.g. "*The immigrant population of X experience low levels of racism.*"

Which is the primary or original meaning: magnitude or collective noun?

**Edit**: So, etymology suggests that the collective noun is the original meaning. When did it change in popular use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the OED, neither one is the original meaning in English. The first citation is from 1544, and is:

> 1. A populated or inhabited place. *Obs.*

And their clearest citation for this sense is:

> 1578   T. Nicholas tr. F. Lopez de Gómara Pleasant *Hist. Conquest W. India*   They received their advise that neere at hand were great populations [Sp. *poblaciones*], and soone after he came to Zimpanzinco.

The next citation not in this sense is:

> 1612   Bacon *Ess.*  Not the hundredth poll will be fit for a helmet, and so great population and little strength.

and most of the early citations after this are in the sense of the magnitude of a group.

Answer (score 2):

Given that the word *population* is derived from the Latin *populus*, which translates as *people*, I believe that it was originally meant to be a collective noun.